# Equalize the chance of drawing the same color marbles from a bag

Tags: probability

There is a bag containing 3 red marbles and 3 blue marbles. Two people are playing a game:

Jessica draws a marble from the bag and does not replace it. Then, Aiden draws a marble from the same bag. If the marbles are the same color, Jessica wins, and if they are different, Aiden wins.

Aiden has an advantage because the chance of drawing different marbles (60%) is higher than the chance of drawing the same marbles (40%).

What combination of red and blue marbles in the bag would make Jessica's and Aiden's chances of winning equal?

Comment: n=3 and m=1 seems to work.  You need $n^2-n+m^2-m-2mn=0$.  Then each player has 1/2 chance of winning.

Comment: I agree with TickaJules's comment, note that for $n=m$ the game is never fair, but for $n=m\to \infty$ we get $P(J win)-P(A win)\to 0$.